# TFS: View checkouts by project

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying out Team Foundation Service and using Visual Studio 2012. Does anyone know how to get a list of which files in a Team Project may be checked out (and by which users) at that moment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a Visual Studio command prompt. Navigate to a valid TFS workspace (e.g. if your workspace is mapped from "$/" to "C:\TFS" then `cd c:\tfs`)

Once you're in the workspace use the command `tf status`

e.g. `tf status $/MyTeamProject /recursive /user:*`

This will show all of the current pending changes in the "MyTeamProject" Team Project